# Video from Vimeo cannot be played into UiWebView Android

Tags: android, ajax, video, uiwebview, vimeo

We are developping a native application included vimeo's videos into a UiWebView Android.
The old and news videos (flash and html5) cannot be played with/without the flash plugin. An error occured :

(First one) E/Web Console(661): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null at http://a.vimeocdn.com/p/1.4.16/js/player.mobile.js:47

(Second error)  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://a.vimeocdn.com/p/1.4.16/html_opt/ming_overlay_outro.html?1337676085504. Origin player.vimeo  at null:1

It seems there is an ajax domain problem. So is there any workaround about that... in vimeo player options or in android code ? Thanks.

Best regards,
Nicolas